# No Notification received for Fan Pages when tagged / @mentioned within Facebook Comments plugin

Tags: notifications, comments, facebook-social-plugins, facebook-comments, fan-page

Using the Facebook *Comments* plugin, you are able to tag / @mention a Facebook *Fan Page* within your comment, yet the *Fan Page* does not receive a Facebook *Notification* when this occurs.

I imagine there has to be an error in the system or user error (probably a user error ;-), because there's really no reason to tag / @mention someone within a Facebook Comments plugin if they're not going to be notified.

Thoughts?

Comment: That's probably intentional.  You could conceivably get thousands of notifications per hour from that.